# Color a complex image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to color the image below using Objective C in iOS.
[image]

I want to color the image based on height. For example the first 10 pixels with red, the next 20 with blue and the next 20 with green. I want the image to be colored like this.

[image]

I have searched in Stack overflow but I am not able find a way to do it.

Thanks

Edit:

This is how I have drawn the image

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 300);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 80, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 150);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 140, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 300);
CGContextClosePath(context);


CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

This is a terrain graph. The points in the graph will be dynamic. So based on the height of the terrain, it has to be colored. So I will not be able to create separate paths for the individual colors as I only get the heights. I do not have any point information for the individual color paths in the graph.

Comment: Color the Image? How is defined your image at start? Any BezierPath/CGPath? Do you know the delimitations?

Comment: u need a separate bezierpath for each color segment u want to fill.

Comment: do u want to fill the whole segment at once / fill it based on touch just like painting ?

Comment: I would color an enclosing rectangle, and then use the image as a mask.

Comment: @Larme I have added code and a bit more explanation

Comment: @Mr.T I will not be able to get separate bezierpaths, as I only have the height information

Comment: @MichaelL Can you please elaborate that. I am not sure I understood that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've already been told, one way is simply to treat your graph shape as a *mask*. The mask means that your graph shape punches a "hole" in the image. The bands of color can simply be three colored rectangular views *behind* the image, easy to create in code. The three rectangular views behind the image show through the hole.

Alternatively, draw the graph shape, then treat the graph shape as a *clipping path* and draw the three colored rectangles.

Using the second approach, I was easily able to get this result:

[image]

Here's the code I used:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3);

// your code:
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 300);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 80, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 150);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 140, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 300);
CGContextClosePath(context);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// my code starts here - first, draw path again:

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 300);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 80, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 150);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 140, 230);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 300);
CGContextClosePath(context);

// clip to that path, and draw the rectangles:
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0,250,300,50));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0,200,300,50));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0,150,300,50));
```

Comment: For a similar example, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202718/341994

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the first method mentioned by @matt

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 300)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 230)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(80, 230)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(120, 150)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(140, 230)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 300)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 0)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[maskPath closePath];
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.maskView.layer.mask = mask;
```

Comment: But you're not showing how to get the colored bands.