# How can I apply a gradient blur effect on a view?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have drawn a path on a view, All I need is to apply a gradient blur effect from the outer edge of the closed drawn path to the view's bounds. My question is mainly about the Gradient blur effect rather than applying it on the path.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this but believe you could make it work:

- create the path
- use the path as a mask can create an new image that is clear outside the path while selecting the interior of the path (the interior has to be opaque)
- use a radial blur on the whole image
- composite the saved interior path OVER the blurred image
- stroke the path to get a clear definition between the original interior and the blurred exterior

Comment: thank you, i will try this approach, actually im doing the same thing in this link but with the blur effect of course (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202228/how-to-fill-a-uibezierpath-with-a-gradient/23202718?noredirect=1#comment58671696_23202718)