# Plotting multiple curves in same graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile-application

[image]

I'm trying implement a graph like the attached image. I tried many open sources but no luck. Can someone help me where can i get this kind of graph.

Comment: You don't "get" a graph. You _create_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the drawing is concerned, it's simply a matter of drawing the pieces in the right order. Let's walk through how you would draw the image shown in your screen shot.

- Draw the whole background first.
- Start with the highest curve. Draw the curve; use the curve as the top of a mask or clipping area, or simply close the curve using the right and bottom boundaries, and fill so that you get the color below it. Now the whole area below it is yellow.
- Do the same with the next curve. Now the whole area below that curve is orange, covering all but the top of the yellow you drew previously.
- Repeat for all the other curves.

Comment: For how to mask so as to fill the area below a curve, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202718/341994 In your case, it's even simpler, because it's a solid fill, whereas in my other answer I'm doing a gradient which is a little more involved.

Comment: Actually you could just use superimposed CAShapeLayers which is even simpler.